# azure webapp deploy java fails on existing app

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a webapp which serves a java rest api. I uploaded the jar file and web.config to a newly deployed app and everything works fine.

I do the upload using the local git (I clone the local git, add the jar and web.config and deploy).

The problem is that if I want to update and change the jar, the deployment fails:

```
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Deployment failed
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://$XXX:YYY@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mysite.git
   b084efd..8a5ce53  master -> master
```

If I stop the webapp, then do the deployment it is successful and the webapp works fine once I restart it.

Is there a way to do it without manually stopping and restarting the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into blue-green deployment? You cannot quite update something that is in use. You can also try to rename the .jar file when committing to git and from the web.config just point to the new .jar file.

Comment: As a restart is required anyway I assumed this would simply work. I cannot use blue-green deployment as I have just one instance.

Comment: Then add another instance. It's not too expensive since you are using this only for the duration of deployment. You can kill the other instance after use. You can also look into how to automate this process so you can integrate it in a deployment pipeline.